# How do I check the validity of a set of inequality constraints?

Tags: r, optimization, algorithms

I have a table of inequality constraints, each with an "x < y" relation. How can I check this table for contradictory logic such as a < b, b < c, c < a?

For example

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(0)
ineqs <- unique(data.table(
  X = sample(head(letters, 5), 5, replace = T),
  Rel = "<",
  Y = sample(head(letters, 5), 5, replace = T)
))

ineqs
   X Rel Y
1: e   < b
2: b   < e
3: c   < d
4: e   < d
```

In this case, a function like `is_valid(constraints)` should obviously return FALSE because the constraints e < b, and b < e are contradictory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *relation matrix* $M(R)$ is the binary indicator of the relation: in this case, the entry in $M(\lt)$ for variables $x,y$ is $1$ (true) when $x\lt y$ and $0$ (false) otherwise.

These individual relationships imply other relationships through the transitivity property $a\lt b$ and $b\lt c$ implies $a\lt c.$  The resulting *transitive closure* of the relation matrix must be consistent with antisymmetry: $M(R)[x,y]=1$ implies $M(R)[y,x]=0.$  The transitive closure is readily (if not entirely efficiently) found by taking powers of $M(R)$ until they stabilize, treating all values of $0$ as false and all nonzero values as true.

Thus, you can systematically check such a relation by (1) generating its matrix, (2) computing its transitive closure, and (3) checking that for (partial) antisymmetry.  This is a general solution for any transitive, partially asymmetric relation, although it needs an (obvious) modification for reflexive relationships like $\le$ (where $M(R)[x,x]=1$ for all $x$).

Below is working `R` code to illustrate.  It checks five relations defined by sets of inequalities (given as character strings involving alpha variables).  Its output is

```
[1] "Invalid: FALSE"
[1] "Valid: TRUE"
[1] "Invalid.2: FALSE"
[1] "Valid.2: TRUE"
[1] "Invalid.3: FALSE"
```

The first term is my indication of whether the relation is valid and the second TRUE/FALSE is the code's determination.  It and I agree.  The first line of output corresponds to the example in the question.

```
constraint.to.matrix <- function(x) {
  ab <- sapply(x, function(s) strsplit(s, "[^[:alpha:]]+"))
  vars <- sort(unique(unlist(ab)))
  n <- length(vars)
  r <- matrix(0, n, n, dimnames=list(vars, vars))
  for (rel in ab) {
    r[rel[1], rel[2]] <- 1
  }
  r
}

is.antisymmetric <- function(r) all(c(t(r) + r + diag(nrow(r))) <= 1)

transitive.closure <- function(r) {
  s <- r + diag(nrow(r)) >= 1
  while(TRUE) {
    r1 <- r %*% s > 0
    if (all(r1 - r == 0)) break
    r <- r1
  }
  r
}

check <- function(constraints) 
  is.antisymmetric(transitive.closure(constraint.to.matrix(constraints)))

trials <- list(Invalid=list("e < b", "b < e", "c < d", "e < d"),
               Valid=list("a<b", "b<c", "c<d"),
               Invalid.2=list("a<b", "b<c", "c<d", "d<a"),
               Valid.2=list(),
               Valid.3=list("a<a"))

for (s in names(trials))  print(paste0(s, ": ", check(trials[[s]])))
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution by @whuber is more complete than this one. However, if one accepts to use the `igraph` package, one can use the graph properties to test for transitivity, so that there is almost no code to write.

Transforming the list of inequalities into a list of edges of a directed graph, we can test whether the graph is acyclic (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph) for a definition).

```
library(igraph)
## Form a graph out of the edge list
gg <- graph_from_edgelist(as.matrix(ineqs[,c(1,3)]), 
    directed = TRUE)
## Test if the graph is a DAG
is_dag(gg)
```

In the case of the data generated above, indeed, the graph is not acyclic and the test returns `FALSE`. (If you change the seed to 1 and keep the code above, you'll generate a DAG: the inequalities do not have any contradiction).

Comment: +1 I ended up using this because it runs significantly faster than whuber's solution on my large-ish dataset.  It's also easier to implement and easier to understand IMO.